# Best way to offer installation of products?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

Just wondering if someone could help me out.

I'm wondering what the best way of offering installation of products is.

I thought of two ways: Making a configurable product with installation as an option (very time consuming to set up and you can't track sales of "installation") or doing it as a grouped product (also time consuming and cumbersome but can track sales).

Is there a better way? I couldn't find any extensions out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to create product with "downloadable product" type  as it comes with an option to upload your installation or software securely.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry I forgot to add that it is optional, but the products need PHYSICAL installation, not virtual.

Comment: Then I would go for "simple product" with custom options!

Comment: No worries, glad I could help!